# Pretty print not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pretty-print

```
matrix = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(matrix)
```

This does not pretty print. It ugly prints.

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

What gives??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because the length of the printed array when on one line is less than the default `width` of 80. You might want to review the [documentation for `pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).

For example, if we do:

```
matrix = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4,width=20)
pp.pprint(matrix)
```

We get:

```
[   [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Oh....I did read the documentation, but not quite carefully enough, it seems. Thanks.

Comment: @Aerovistae Didn't mean to imply you hadn't just pointing it out for others who might read the question later. Sometimes its helpful to have another set of eyes on these things. Happens to all of us!